# CartThrob - Price Modifier with additional column

Tags: cartthrob

I have a Price Modifier for a product which has the usual option_value, option_name and price. I have added an additional column titled 'supplementary'.

This new column is correctly appearing within the Add to Cart form using the {supplementary} tag as follows;

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form entry_id="{entry_id}"}

    {my_option}
    <input type="hidden" name="item_options[{count}][my_option]" value="{option_value}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_options[supplementary]" value="supplementary" /> 
    {option_name} {supplementary} {price}
    {/my_option}

{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

However, I need this to also appear in the Basket/Cart with the selected option but it's not appearing with the following code;

```
{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}" row_id="{row_id}"}
{option_label}: {option_value} {supplementary}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
```

I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried using the following but to no avail;

{item_options:supplementary}

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. After further trial and error I resolved my own question. Here's the answer in case anyone else gets stuck with something similar;

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form entry_id="{entry_id}"}

    {my_option}
    <input type="hidden" name="item_options[{count}][my_option]" value="{option_value}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_options[{count}][additional_column]" value="{additional_column}" /> 
    {option_name} {additional_column} {price}
    {/my_option}

{/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

No need to add the additional column tag to Basket/Cart. It just outputs automatically with the following;

```
{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}" row_id="{row_id}"}
{option_label}: {option_value}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! You can accept your own answer to show this question as answered in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Just had to wait a few days to be able to answer my own question. :)